# JS: Array.push() fails to add same object twice, even when Array is reinitiallized

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, thingsboard

I'm using *Javascript* and *D3.js* to create a *Custom Widget* in Thingsboard. I've managed to make a Chart work that plots a line from a given datasource. But I'm facing an issue when changing the datasource.
When user clicks on a new datasource, it should replaced the data on the graph. My *D3.js* chart takes data from an Array of point objects, with *X* and *Y* coordinates, that's generated from the datasource.

But I'm having the following issue: The dataset array gets the data correctly *only the first time* that it gets the points pushed. Whenever I try to clear the array or remove the dataset, and *reapply the points*, it acts as if the points were already there, but hiden. The problem will be clearer if you look at the *Console* log output.
Notice that the Array acts as if it was always the same/It contained the same points, even when I renew it with:

```
dataset = [];
```

I'm new to Javascript so this could be a very dumb problem, but I cannot find any similar issues nor know how to look for the issue.

My dataset is coded in a string like this:

```
"25,351,-442,0,112,3447,28,45,..."
```

Here's the code of my updating function:

```
var dataset = [];

function addDataPoint (value) {
        //widget = this;
        widget.string = value + ''; //Prevents compile error from .split()
        var pointsArray = [];
        var pointsArray = widget.string.split(',');
        var newList = []; //As dataset is referenced by the D3.js chart, I wanted to test with an Unreferenced array to check if it had something to do with the reference.
        console.log("PointsArrayLength " + pointsArray.length);
        for (var index = 0; index < pointsArray.length; index++){
            var number = parseInt(pointsArray[index],10);
            var point = {
                x: index % self.ctx.settings.xRangeMax,
                y: number
            };
            if (widget.lastX && widget.lastX > point.x) {
                //widget.data.length = 0;
            }else{
            if(!isNaN(number)){
                widget.lastX = point.x;
                newList.push(point);
                dataset.push(point);
            }

            }
        }
        console.log("UnreferencedList Length: " +newList.length + " Index: "+index);
            console.log("Referenced length: " + dataset.length);
        //Redraw the graph    
        widget.line.attr('d', widget.lineGenerator);

    }
//The function that gets called when the dataset changes.
self.onDataUpdated = function() {
var xValueString;
try{
    var xValueString = self.ctx.defaultSubscription.data[0].data[0][1];
    console.log("Size of data: " + xValueString.length);
    dataset = [];//NOTE
    /* I've tried several methods here to renew the Array. 
     dataset.length = 0 ; a while loop with dataset.pop() until length = 0, etc.
    None of the methods make a difference*/
    addDataPoint(xValueString);
    console.log("Size of data: " + dataset.length);

} catch(err){
        //For other debugging purposes
        //console.log(err);

}
```

And here's the output from the *Console Log*:

```
//First run on dataset number 1:
Size of data: 55411
PointsArrayLength 3001
UnreferencedList Length: 3000 Index: 3001
Referenced length: 3000
Size of data: 3000

//First run on dataset Number 2:
//Note: Dataset Number 2 contains dataset number 1, and adds 12879 more points
Size of data: 69021
PointsArrayLength 15879
UnreferencedList Length: 12879 Index: 15879
Referenced length: 12879
Size of data: 12879
//Second Run on dataset number 1:
Size of data: 55411
PointsArrayLength 3001
UnreferencedList Length: 0 Index: 3001
Referenced length: 0
Size of data: 0
//Second Run on dataset Number 2:
Size of data: 69021
PointsArrayLength 15879
UnreferencedList Length: 1 Index: 15879
Referenced length: 1
Size of data: 1
```

Comment: where is `dataset` declared in your code? Like `var dataset = []` or something similar?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. I'll edit to add it

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are having scope issues.  Define newlist as a global var.

```
let dataset = [];
let newlist = [];

function addDataPoint (value) {
    //widget = this;
    widget.string = value + ''; //Prevents compile error from .split()
    let workArray = []
    let pointsArray = [];
    pointsArray = widget.string.split(',');

    console.log("PointsArrayLength " + pointsArray.length);
    for (var index = 0; index < pointsArray.length; index++){
        var number = parseInt(pointsArray[index],10);
        var point = {
            x: index % self.ctx.settings.xRangeMax,
            y: number
        };
        if (widget.lastX && widget.lastX > point.x) {
            //widget.data.length = 0;
        }else{
        if(!isNaN(number)){
            widget.lastX = point.x;
            newList.push(point);
            //dataset.push(point);
            workArray.push(point);
        }

        }
    }
    console.log("UnreferencedList Length: " +newList.length + " Index: "+index);
        console.log("Referenced length: " + dataset.length);
    //Redraw the graph    
    widget.line.attr('d', widget.lineGenerator);
    return workArray;
}
//The function that gets called when the dataset changes.
self.onDataUpdated = function() {

try{
    let xValueString = self.ctx.defaultSubscription.data[0].data[0][1];
    console.log("Size of data: " + xValueString.length);
    //dataset = [];//NOTE
    /* I've tried several methods here to renew the Array. 
    dataset.length = 0 ; 
    None of the methods make a difference*/
    dataset = addDataPoint(xValueString);
    console.log("Size of data: " + dataset.length);

    } catch(err){

}
```

Comment: Have also tested your code: The General issue remains. The newList array won't add the same point twice, so the length doesn't change, and the workArray acts as if the points where there already but without any length.